# Вставить переменные из lua в bash

Tags: linux, bash, lua

В lua скрипте есть 2 переменные. Нужно вставить их в `bash` команду. Либо подсунуть в `bash` скрипт как-то.

`os.execute("psql -h localhost -U user -d psql_db_name -c 'insert into table  values(".. lua_arg1 ..",".. lua_arg2 ..");`

Все работает нормально, но bash команда должна выглядеть следующим образом:
`insert into table  values('lua_arg1_value','lua_arg2_value')`
у меня же получается на выходе:
`insert into table  values(lua_arg1_value,lua_arg2_value)`
т.к. переменная уже пишется в кавычках. двойные кавычки типо `'" "'` не работают.

Вариант номер 2. Отдать переменную в bash скрипт:
`os.execute("/tmp/test/bash1.sh " .. lua_arg1)`
Но как тогда в самом скрипте получить это значение, чтоб им оперировать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

насколько я понимаю, вам нужно добиться появления двух видов кавычек в строке, передаваемой аргументом функции `os.execute()`. можно сделать это как минимум двумя способами (вместо `os.execute()` я использовал `print()`):

```lua
lua_arg1 = "строка 1"
lua_arg2 = "строка 2"
print("вариант1 -c 'insert into table  values(\"" .. lua_arg1 ..
  "\",\"" .. lua_arg2 .."\")'")
print("вариант2 -c \"insert into table  values('" .. lua_arg1 ..
  "','" .. lua_arg2 .."')\"")
```

результат выполнения:

```
вариант1 -c 'insert into table  values("строка 1","строка 2")'
вариант2 -c "insert into table  values('строка 1','строка 2')"
```

---

> Вариант номер 2

в *posix*-совместимых *shell*-ах обращаться к аргументам можно по «номерным» переменным:

```sh
echo $1 # вывод первого аргумента
echo $2 # вывод второго аргумента
...
```

---

**дополнение**

а вообще вам, вероятно, имеет больший смысл воспользоваться какой-нибудь библиотекой связи между *lua* и *postgresql*: [lua-sql-postgres](https://packages.debian.org/wheezy/lua-sql-postgres), [lua-sql](https://admin.fedoraproject.org/pkgdb/package/lua-sql/) и тому подобными.

Comment: Попробовал ваши варианты. `insert into users vlues(\"" .. lua_arg1 ..
  "\")` на выходе имею `insert into users values("lua_arg1_value");`
Уже гораздо лучше, но мне нужны одинарные кавычки....
вариант с `insert into users vlues(\'" .. lua_arg1 .. "\')` - выдает значение без кавычек

Comment: второй предложенный вариант и использует одинарные кавычки вокруг аргументов.

Comment: я сделал дополнение по поводу psql.

Comment: Да, второй вариант помог! Спасибо огромное!
Сразу не стал его даже пробовать - смутила конструкция `\"insert into` - думал что вы описались. До сих пор не понял - почему ковычки ставятся именно там..=\